# import multiple packages at once in vscode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, visual-studio-code

Imagine I have a file with so many unimported packages like this (in flutter):

```
Undefined class 'A'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name.
...
...
...
Undefined class 'Z'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name.
```

I do not want to do ctrl + . on all of them to import them one by one; what I want to do is import all of them at once. how can I acheive that in vs code?
I have already searched here but did not find any solution.

Comment: I think there is no answer for vscode in general. It depends on your language and the corresponding extension providing the language support. E.g. in typescript with the correct extension installed, you get the option _Add all missing imports_ when you press [Ctrl]+[.]

Comment: Exactly, there is such a thing for typscript but I did not find it for flutter!